# Break long text area text into new line for each comma in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

Really need help in getting this over the line. I have a long text area like this:

> Policy Type: Accidental Damage (SCTP), Policy Start Date: 27/03/2022, Acceptance Criteria: All default to No, Insured Name: Account Name, Date of Birth of Oldest Insured: Date of birth of primary contact, Existing Policy With Selected Insurers: No (SCTP), Holding Broker: Yes, Holding Underwriter: Other With no insurer specified

, which needs to be like this:

> Policy Type: Accidental Damage (SCTP)
>
> Policy Start Date: 27/03/2022
>
> Acceptance Criteria: All default to No

and so on.. This needs to be in a flow as I am copying this from property long text area to opp long text area filed.

I have tried BR() and substitute so far, but they don't seem to work.

`SUBSTITUTE( JSENCODE( {!fieldname} ) , 'undefined\r\n', '<br>')`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can’t use long text area, encrypted, or Description fields in formulas.
```

[Doc Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)

Sadly, Text Area Long fields are ill-supported in the SFDC Formula language. See [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjTTUAZ/text-area-long-formula-support)

You're going to need to escape to an Apex Action to do the reformatting